# Style all but one element to dim background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, compass-sass

Looking to achieve a dimmed-background effect by dimming (or changing the opacity of) all elements on the page but one; I've been trying out `:not()` as well as some jQuery selectors to try and exclude all but the element, but to no avail. Does anyone know of the best way to do this with SASS/Compass or, failing that, jQuery?

So far, I've tried things like:

```
.opacityFade:not(.classToExclude) {
   STYLES HERE
 }
```

or

```
   $('controlElement').click(function(){
     $(body).not('desiredTargetToExclude').toggleClass('classThatFadesStuffOut');
});
```

Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to write more JS and better separate responsibilities,but there might not be a way to do that. Little new to Front-End development, so I'm not aware of a best way to go about doing this; thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by placing a blanket over all elements, and then pulling the element you want to display out of the DOM order with the z-index property

```
.item {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}

.item.selected {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200
}

.blanket {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Note that the element needs to have a non static position.

See http://jsfiddle.net/cyberdash/fCMaT/

Comment: This has some important caveat: if the element has a transparent background (relies on some parent's background color), the "blanket" will mess with it, the background of the object you want to highlight will also dim

Answer (score 0):

you could add another class to the non-dimmed/active div. I'll put together a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nqT7V/

In Jquery:

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().addClass("dimmed");
    $this.parent().find(".item").removeClass("active");
    $this.addClass("active");
});

$(".holder").click(function(e){
    if (e.target != this) return;
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("dimmed")){
        $this
            .removeClass("dimmed")
            .find(".item").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```